Trying to port forward ZTE F673A v9 for Fightcade 2

This is supposed to be the section where I port forward but I have no idea on what to do here. I'm supposed to port forward ports UDP 6000-6009 and TCP 7000.
Any guidance?

Does your ISP support port forwarding?

I don't know. Is there a way to check? Or do I have to contact them?

Just google [YourISP] + CG-NAT... If the results point to it using CG-NAT, there's your answer, you can't.
